# Executing command line from python that contains spaces

Tags: python, command-line

I try to automatise an image stitching process from python using the software PTGui.
I can execute the following command which works perfectly in the windows command line :

*C:\Users\mw4168> "C:\Program Files\PTGui\ptgui.exe" -batch "C:\Users\mw4168\OneDrive\Desktop\PTGui Tests\3 rows\Panorama.pts"*
[command screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNISC.png)

However, when I try to execute this command using os.system or subprocess.run in Python:

```
import os
os.system("C:\Program Files\PTGui\ptgui.exe" + "-batch" +"C:\Users\mw4168\OneDrive\Desktop\PTGui Tests\3 rows\panorama.pts")
```

I get this error :

*'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*
[error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlSPu.png)

It seems that there is an issue with the spaces within the string... Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Paul

Comment: can you post the part of that code where you execute the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the `os.system` documentation already tells you, a better solution altogether is to use `subprocess` instead.

```
subprocess.run([
    r"C:\Program Files\PTGui\ptgui.exe",
    "-batch",
    r"C:\Users\mw4168\OneDrive\Desktop\PTGui Tests\3 rows\panorama.pts"])
```

The string you created also lacked spaces between the indvidual arguments; but letting Python pass the arguments to the OS instead also gives you more control over quoting etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're probably (as you have posted no code) not passing the `C:\Program Files\PTGui\ptgui.exe` as a string to the terminal but just a plain command

Use

```
import os
os.system('\"C:\Program Files\PTGui\ptgui.exe\" -batch')
```

Comment: Thank for you answer. I'm not sure to understand what you mean.. I edited my post to add the code

Comment: @PaulGALTIER as your code shows, you're parsing the path of your .exe directly in the command line. That is the same as writing `C:\Users\mw4168> C:\Program Files\PTGui\ptgui.exe -batch`. Check the code on my answer to correctly use the `os.system()`. The `\` before `"` makes `"` be read as a character instead of being the string separator